Syncing different audio streams for one video
So I wish to have a raspberry pi broadcasting wifi and a web server with PHP\Python cgi-bin. Th objective is to be able to receive up to 5 different short streams (up to 3 minutes) from people and sync them (to the millisecond). Here is the plan:

Use an HTML with getUserMedia method to get video\audio from the user.
Upload the blob produced to the raspberry, along with an argument containing Date.now() that I produced when the users started their recording (thus giving me the knowledge of the difference in ms between all medias).
At the server side all files are trimmed (using ffmpeg or somthing) to the same length, while their starting point trimmed according to the data received from Date.now().

Now, I foresee a possible issue: what if not all users have the same time on their devices (e.g. due to using different cell providers)? Is there such possibility?
Is there a way for me to sync all local time of the browsers while using the... uuuuuuum... let's call it an app? Does connection speed and lags due to system resources may cause deltas in ms between the users?


…and sync them (to the millisecond).

Not physically possible.
Even if you assume that all devices had exactly the same time at one moment, down to the nanosecond or even better, you cannot assume that the next sample or frame will be in sync.  Each device has its own clock and will drift from the others.  What may be 48 kHz to your device's audio interface might be 48.001 kHz to mine.  You can certainly expect millisecond-scale drift over the course of a few minutes between arbitrary consumer devices.
You need to completely re-think your approach.  What do you actually want your videos to be relative to?
For example, it was popular awhile back for several people to dub over a musician's video, adding their own music track.  Another musician would add another, and another.  Even after dozens did this, they all remained in-sync.  The reason is that the dubbing musicians device was playing and recording at the same time, so that the pre-recorded video was being played back with the same clock that the derivative video was being recorded.
If your videos must be live, then you need some common clock source, and I don't mean clock-on-the-wall time.  In the professional world, it's common to actually use GNSS receivers which provide clock references with very high reliability.
Only once you've decided how to solve this at this finer scale can you begin to figure out how you'll handle actual time offsets.

Update
With more information known from the discussion in comments, let me clarify a bit more.
The scenario as I understand it is two to five devices in a room, all recording simultaneously.  One device will serve as the camera and will record video.  The other devices will record audio, as a sort of lavalier microphone.
Now, back to the original goal of strict synchronization... no, it is still not possible.  As stated previously, these devices are going to drift on their own because there is no common clock reference.  That includes clock-on-the-wall time, and audio sample clock.  They'll be close, but they will drift.
So, what to do?  Change your requirements.  This is why I was insisting on knowing what we're actually doing here.  We can't cheat physics, so we need to figure out what tradeoffs we need to make to end up with something functional.  Here are some of the possibilities.
Record live like a WebRTC conference call
The whole WebRTC stack is set up for low latency, and it has a lot of stuff for resampling audio to keep it as realtime as possible.  Additionally, the usual implementations of the media capture side have built-in noise cancellation and automatic gain control.  These are brutal for music, but suitable for your use case of people speaking.
Basically, you'd create a WebRTC call between all the devices in the session and a "server" that would do the recording.  This could be your Pi, or even an app on one of the phones.  You'll undoubtedly get a little echo when voices are picked up by multiple microphones, but many mobile devices are pretty good with noise cancellation these days by using phased directional microphones.  Is it good enough?  You'll have to experiment to find out.  The good news is that you can test without building anything.  Start up a Google Meet or similar, join some 'microphone' devices together, and record, and give it a try.
Ignore the consequences, fix it in post
You could just basically record on all the devices and then assemble the audio manually later.  Just remember... streams will drift over time, so it's not enough to just set initial offsets.
Pick one mic at a time
This can be applied to any method... if someone is speaking, mute or attenuate the other mics.  A WebRTC MCU will do this for you.
Don't.  Do something different instead.
If the imperfect solutions aren't of good enough quality, consider doing something different.  While having a mic on each person is one of the better ways to pick up those voices, it's not the only way.  You could simply have a better placed omnidirectional mic in the room and connect it to the video recording device.  There are conference room array microphones you could get that use beamforming phased arrays to "zoom in" on a voice.
Whatever solution you choose, just remember the physics of the problem you're trying to solve, and the tradeoffs you're willing to make.  No solution is perfect in every way.

First, Thanks. Second, Ouch! that was harsh (but again, thanks)... What I wanted was to device a "simple and affordable" method to have one video with multiple audio sources, without having "echos" and\or picture-sound-lags. this was meant for occupational therapists.

Can you say how many ms will become audible\noticeable?

Again though, what are all these recordings going to be relative to, in time?  Describe your product more... are these therapists responding to something?  Seems weird that there would just be five arbitrary videos you'd want to play simultaneously... what's the context?

Perhaps I was not specific enough. The therapists will you a video (recorded by one camera) to "act" a simulation of real life issues. Their patients will be able to deduce "correct" solutions for these issues (as per each disability, that is being treated by the therapist). If needed, it is best to better hear the "actors" thus I want to have additional audio from each actor. I wish for it to be as simple and inexpensive as possible, so it will be adopted by as many people as possible.

I think I need to tell the "actors" to add an audible sign I can recognize and then I can sync (almost) to the ms. the questions are: What and how? The what can be a clapper. Now it's the "how?" as I am not dealing with professional equipment or software (simple and inexpensive) I can send them over to Adobe premier or whatever. The solution needs to be automatic and as immediate as possible.

So, the therapist will record a video with instructions.  An actor will hear/see these instructors from the therapist.  Then they will record themselves acting and send that back.  Right?  What I don't understand though is what are all the individual actors doing that needs to be in-sync?  What are we synchronizing?

I want that all "actors" will be heard well on the final product, thus each "actor" uses his\her phone to grab audio close to him\her (e.g. bluetooth mic, phone on desk, phone in a pocket etc.) this is while the therapist records the video.

Wait, so, the therapist and actors are in the same room together?  And you're just looking for a way to multitrack audio?  Please explain the entire scenario in detail about what you're trying to do rather than trickling out information like this.  If the therapist is recording their video and you just need an additional audio channel from someone else, then you should use WebRTC to get that audio to the therapist and record there.  The WebRTC stack will keep things in-sync as best as it can.  If everyone is in the same room though, just use a multitrack audio interface.

@AlonBR I do not grok what your specific task is.  I can't figure out what you're trying to build.  No matter what you do, time is relative and requires some sort of reference.  If each device runs independently, then they all have their own concept of time.  Different clock-on-the-wall time, different exact frame rates, different audio sample rates.  If you want to synchronize all of these but still have the devices running independently, then you must resample audio and stretch framerate, but to know by how much and which direction is dependent on what specifically you're trying to do.

First, I thought I was clear enough. Sorry for that. Second, using WebRTC in real time doesn't mean that I need a "server" running? Can I stream all devices to one server and let it aggregate all streams? If so, this means, that on the server side I need to recognize video stream from one device and audio from all others. Right?

No need for a 'server' per se.  WebRTC media streaming is built around maintaining low latency, which means it's always doing that resampling work to keep things as quick as it can.  That means your frame of references is "realtime"... just keep in mind, what's "realtime" can vary by hundreds of milliseconds.  That's why the specific requirements matter.  WebRTC is peer-to-peer, it just needs a server of some sort to set up signalling... but you can implement that in your app.

I feel like I'm beyond help by now...  The scenario is as follows: The therapist is in a room with one-four "actors". they perform a real life issue that may rise in day to day life. I want this scene to be captured as video preferably by the therapist's phone (simple and inexpensive) and have a few additional audio streams added from the "actors", so the sound will be the best it can be. Again sorry for not being clear enough in the first place.

No need to apologize, I think I understand now.  2-5 devices in a room, you want to use a camera from one, microphones from the others, and keep them all in-sync so you can mix those inputs into a video with a regular mixed audio track.  Is that correct?

That's right. OK, but with no server, I will not have recording capabilities, would I? Or am I missing something? As long as I have the server it can do the "leg work" of combining the streams. (By server I am talking about a Raspberry pi or something)

Updated the answer.

Thanks. I'll try the different methods and find the tradeoff I can live with. :-) One more thing (If it's of any interest for you), regarding drifting: in a two to three minutes scene, I will probably be OK. ;-)

Yeah, if it's just 2-3 minutes then clock drift won't be so much of an issue.  Though, random dropouts do happen on rare occasion... power saving on mobile devices gets reeeeaaally buggy sometimes.
